# (PHP) Why after some looping, the function doesn't called anymore?

Tags: php, function

I have query below:

```
$r = "Query goes here...";
$r = conn::execq($q);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
   $q = "Query goes here..."; //The $fetch value above is inserted here as 'WHERE' clause
   $r = conn::execq($q); //--> The problem
   $r = mysqli_fetch_row($r);

   if($r > 0) print "ok<br/>";
   else print "failed<br/>";
}
```

And in class "**conn**" function "**execq**":

```
public static function execq($q) {
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    return $r;
}
```

The **execq** function doesn't called after some looping. The first query has been executed successfully, and then the second query being executed. After some looping, the query being stopped to called the function "conn::execq". Any ideas? Thanks..

**--- EDIT ---**

```
conn:openconn(); //Open connection   

$r = "Query goes here...";
$r = conn::execq($q);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
   $q = "Query goes here..."; //The $fetch value above is inserted here as 'WHERE' clause
   $r = conn::execq($q); //--> The problem
   $r = mysqli_fetch_row($r);

   if($r > 0) print "ok<br/>";
   else print "failed<br/>";
}

conn:closeconn(); //Close connection
```

And in class "**conn**":

```
public static function openconn() {
    global $dbc;
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

public static function closeconn() {
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}

public static function execq($q) {        
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);        
    return $r;
}
```

And now I've got:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in ...
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to open the database connection each time?

Comment: why you are doing connect/disconnect every time?

Comment: Ic the problem now. But I've separated the function above onto "openconn" and "closeconn" and I still got an error..

Comment: Shouldn't it be **conn::openconn();** and **conn::closeconn();** ??

Comment: @Dr.Dan: I didn't catch what you mean. Could you pls explain?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 You are calling openconn & closeconn functions as **conn:openconn;  & conn:closeconn;** Change them to **conn::openconn(); and conn::closeconn();**

Comment: VARIABLE SCOPE! A variable defined in one function is not automagically available in another!

Comment: @deceze: OK ic. So sorry because I am beginner in PHP. How to make it possible to access from another function? I've edited the code above, pls take a look..

Comment: You already know how to `return` values from functions and how to pass values to functions as arguments. *That* way. Since all your database functions consist of a single call to another function though, it's not really worth it to wrap them in the first place it would seem. Either get rid of them, or learn how to do a real object-oriented solution.

Comment: I've edited the code above, pls take a look. Still has no luck. I've completely out of idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are opening and closing the database connection several times in very short order; this is horribly inefficient. Keep reusing *one* open connection!
2. You are trying to use `mysqli_fetch_row` on a resource *after* its connection has already been closed. This should not work at all.
3. You are overwriting the resource `$r` inside your loop, so the resource `$r` in your `while` condition will not yield any more results and the iteration ends.
4. You should try to make *one* slightly more complex SQL query to get the information you want instead of generating more and more queries by looping over the result of the first query. The database can often do much more work for you than you think.

Comment: I agree, romove mysqli_close($dbc); from your exexq function and add it explicitly after your while loop or call a function containing it